# Drop DB using MSBuild even if in use

Tags: sql-server, msbuild, sqlcmd

I am using the following command in my MSBuild file to drop a database

```
sqlcmd -E -S <ServerName> -Q "DROP DATABASE <DBName>"
```

But sometimes I get the error

> Cannot drop database  because it is currently in use.

What command should I use so that the DB is dropped even if it is in use?

Comment: Close all connections to the DB and then try DROP DATABASE command.

Comment: how do I close all connections to the DB using sqlcmd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To kill all connections to your database. See [Kill All Active Connections To A Database](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Kill_All_Active_Connections_To_A_Database)

Now issue your DROP DATABASE command after the above procedure.

Answer (score 19):

You can set your database to `SINGLE_USER` to drop all existing connections.

```
sqlcmd -E -S <ServerName> -Q "ALTER DATABASE <DBName> SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE"
sqlcmd -E -S <ServerName> -Q "DROP DATABASE <DBName>"
```

This is preferred to looping over each of the connections and dropping them one by one, because some applications will immediately reconnect.

Comment: It also prevents new users from connecting;-)

Comment: @Michael Thanks for posting the very short answer instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use something like this:

```
sqlcmd -S servername\instance -Q"use master;DROP DATABASE yourdatabase"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sqlcmd -S .\MAPS -Q "RESTORE DATABASE Awards FROM DISK = 'C:\Awards_Project
\Awards_FULL.bak' WITH REPLACE, MOVE 'Awards' to 'C:\Awards_Project\Awards.mdf',
MOVE 'Awards_log' to 'C:\Awards_Project\Awards.ldf'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively restart the sql service and then perform the drop e.g. in a `myfile.bat`

```
@echo off
REM Requires administrative rights to restart service
REM open powershell and execute command in administrative mode
powershell -Command "Start-Process 'cmd' -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/c net stop MSSQLSERVER && net start MSSQLSERVER && exit'"      
echo Please wait ~10 seconds for sql service to restart. 
Timeout /t 10 /nobreak
echo Dropping database. 
sqlcmd -S localhost -Q "drop database [database Name]"
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot drop a database that is in use. [Check link for ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178613.aspx)

Comment: So, is there some way using sqlcmd that I can close all existing connection?